# How do I fit a model without specifying the number of variables?

Tags: r

I have a data.frame, df, with n variables in it. The variables can take any name.

I want to be able to fit coxph(Surv(time_to_event,bad_outcome)~var1+var2+...+varn,data=df)

But df is a variable, its length can change. How do I write a piece of code that can fit all the variables in df regardless of the number of variables in df and the names of the variables?

Thank you so much.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Read ?formula:

> There are two special interpretations
>   of ‘.’ in a formula.  The usual one is
>   in the context of a ‘data’ argument of
>   model fitting functions and means ‘all
>   columns not otherwise in the formula’:
>   see ‘terms.formula’.  In the context
>   of ‘update.formula’, *only*, it means
>   ‘what was previously in this part of
>   the formula’.

Comment: # Thanks I've done it!
# suppose names contains 
names = names(df)
s = Surv(time_to_event$time_to_event ,bad_outcome$bad_outcome )
fmla = as.formula(paste("s ~",paste(names,collapse="+")))
coxph(fmla,method="breslow",data=df)

Comment: Why not use '.'?
coxph("s ~ .", method="breslow", data=df)

Comment: Great to have you on stackoverflow!