# short formula call for many variables when building a model

Tags: r, r-formula

I am trying to build a regression model with `lm(...)`. My dataset has lots of features( >50). I do not want to write my code as:

```
lm(output ~ feature1 + feature2 + feature3 + ... + feature70)
```

I was wondering what is the short hand notation to write this code?

Comment: The first result of the search "[r] formula many variables" answers your question.

Comment: Duplicate of [How do I fit a model without specifying the number of variables?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3384567/271616) and [how to succinctly write a formula with many variables from a data frame?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5251507/271616) and [Specifying formula in R with glm without explicit declaration of each covariate](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3588961/271616).

Comment: See also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4951442/formula-with-dynamic-number-of-variables

Answer (score 60, accepted):

You can use `.` as described in the help page for `formula`. The `.` stands for "all columns not otherwise in the formula".

`lm(output ~ ., data = myData)`.

Alternatively, construct the formula manually with `paste`. This example is from the `as.formula()` help page:

```
xnam <- paste("x", 1:25, sep="")
(fmla <- as.formula(paste("y ~ ", paste(xnam, collapse= "+"))))
```

You can then insert this object into regression function: `lm(fmla, data = myData)`.

Answer (score 6):

Could also try things like:

```
lm(output ~ myData[,2:71], data=myData)
```

Assuming output is the first column feature1:feature70 are the next 70 columns.

Or

```
features <- paste("feature",1:70, sep="")
lm(output ~ myData[,features], data=myData)
```

Is probably smarter as it doesn't matter where in amongst your data the columns are.

Might cause issues if there's row's removed for NA's though...

Comment: This isn't working for me using data.table