# Feeding large amounts of data into neuralnet function in R

Tags: r, neural-network, conv-neural-network

How would one feed say, 100 different cases into the `neuralnet()` function found in the `neuralnet` package without maunally inputting them.

If there is a dataframe with `colnames(df) = "one","two","three"..."one hundred"`

and I want to use each column as an input into a neural network, is there a way to apply the `neuralnet` function as such:

```
nn <- neuralnet(one~two+three+four+five+six+seven+eight...+one hundred, data=df, 
      err.fct = 'sse', linear.output = F, likelihood=T)
```

without actually typing all one hundred colnames.

---

---

I have tried inputting:

```
nn <- neuralnet(one~as.factor(paste(names(df)[-1], collapse="+")) data=df, 
      err.fct = 'sse', linear.output = F, likelihood=T)
```

and recieved the error

```
Error in model.frame.default(formula.reverse, data) : 
  variable lengths differ (found for 'as.factor(paste(names(df)[-1], collapse="+"))')
```

Comment: use a dot. `nn <- neuralnet(one~., data=df, 
      err.fct = 'sse', linear.output = F, likelihood=T)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Might be a duplicate question.
Edit: @Hong Ooi pointed out the  "dot solution" doesnt work  in `neuralnet()`.

```
dta <- data.frame(a=rnorm(10), a2=rnorm(10), a3=rnorm(10))
frm <- as.formula(paste(names(dta)[1], " ~ ", paste(names(dta)[-1], collapse= "+")))
nn <- neuralnet(frm, data=dta, err.fct = 'sse', linear.output = F, likelihood=T)
```

Comment: Thank you. Sorry If duplicate could not find anything of the likes. If you do please let me know and will delete

Comment: I just remember learning the dot here :D I dont mind about it. Does it work for you?

Comment: Receiving error message: `Error in terms.formula(formula) : '.' in formula and no 'data' argument`

Comment: Did you leave out the `data=df` specification? I made an edit and provided a simple example.

Comment: No its still in there. Strange error as it looks like its stopping at the period and not reading the following comma.

Comment: My actual application is: `neuralnet(CRISPR.Count.....assembled~. , data=Data.Fitted[,-c(1:7)], err.fct = 'sse', linear.output = F, likelihood=T)`

Comment: The neuralnet package is horrible in how it handles formulas. That's why the dot doesn't work.

Comment: The name is actually `CRISPR.Count * assembled`, as from the IMG genome database, but for some reason, Rstudio is recognizing it as `CRISPR.Count.....assembled`. Haha forgive me for my lack of knowledge I'm only a high schooler :D

Comment: any suggestions? @HongOoi

Comment: good point @Hong Ooi. I found a similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5774813/short-formula-call-for-many-variables-when-building-a-model. But i wouldnt mark it as a duplicate as it is worth knowing that the dot solution doesnt work with `neuralnet()`. I made an edit, with a working solution - assuming your dependent variable is at the first position of the array. You get adapt that to your data.

Comment: Thank You! It works perfectly. I was not aware of the `as.formula` function. @BigDataScientist